# Controller testing Rspec, Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am just starting with RSpec and I am a bit lost. Can anyone please tell me how to write controller test for this method?

```
def list_c
    @c = params.has_key?(:car) ? Car.new(car_listing_params) : Car.new()
    @car.user = @user
    @car.number_of_beds = 4 unless @car.number_of_beds
    @car.car_type_tag = 'car' unless @car.car_type
    @page_title = t('home.list_your_car')
end
```

Comment: It requires overly broad answer although I can give you a small test example.

Comment: Anything you think that would put me in the right direction of testing this would help. Thanks.

Comment: yes check my answer. this can very complex. I just tried to give you a hint with comment. Feel free to comment if you don't get any point.

Answer (score 0):

A small example of controller test with rspec. You may get some idea from here.
    # define your helper here.
    require 'rails_helper'

```
# respect method to define test for your controller.
RSpec.describe YourController, type: :controller do
   #define your factories for the set of your test
   # you will decide which one you need to create from factory. Factory girl
   # is used to mock factories.
   # @c = params.has_key?(:car) ? Car.new(car_listing_params) : Car.new()
   # @car.user = @user
   # @car.number_of_beds = 4 unless @car.number_of_beds
   # @car.car_type_tag = 'car' unless @car.car_type
   # @page_title = t('home.list_your_car')

   let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

   before { sign_in user }

  describe '#title' do
    context 'with valid params' do
      before do
        # in before block, you can request a http call 
        # with parameter. This action repeats before each test runs.
        get :your_action_of_current_controller, {a_param: a_value, a_date: "16-4-2015"}
      end

      it "renders successfully" do
        # when you call a get request it assigns a response object.
        expect(response).to be_success
      end

      it "returns json" do
       expect(response.content_type).to be == 'application/json'
      end
    end
   end 
 end
```

Comment: Thank you. One question: How do I specifically test if loop? Like this one: '@c = params.has_key?(:car) ? Car.new(car_listing_params) : Car.new()'

Comment: Just in your get request as I added in the before block you have to send the parameters like controller receive. After submitting that you can test if a new row has been added by following types of code:
``` expect{Foo.bar}.to change{Counter.count}.by 1 ``` assuming Counter has 0 counts before.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this was as well.